# How to get around "call to this must be first statement in constructor"?

Tags: java

I'm coding up a barebones game, and I want to easily construct "monsters" with keywords instead of having to enter in all the attributes every time.

```
class Target {
    public Target(String code) {
        if (code.equals("biggest boss")) {
            this.(code, 50);
        } else if (code.equals("minion")) {
            this.(code, 4);
        }
    }

    public Target(String name, int health 
                  /*various other attributes here */) {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = health;
    }

    String name;
    int health;
}
```

But of course when I run this I get the error `call to this must be first statement in constructor`. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is no "getting around it". Assuming you only have two conditions as shown, you **could** do

```
this(code, "biggest boss".equals(code) ? 50 : 40);
```

**or** use a `Map<String, Integer>` and `map.get(code)` to resolve the value - but `this` has to be the first line if you want to invoke another constructor in the current class.

Answer (score 1):

why would you need to when you can do

```
public Target(String code) {
    this.code = code;
    if (code.equals("biggest boss")) {
        this.health = 50;
    } else if (code.equals("minion")) {
        this.health = 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is DRY to reuse the existing constructor.

Comment: @lexicore It sure is, but sometimes you gotta live dangerously